# how to show selectors on Xamarin.Forms.maps.map

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

My app has a map component that I create within a Stacklayout in the XAML like this:

```
    <maps:Map x:Name="amap">
        <x:Arguments>
            <maps:MapSpan>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <maps:Position>
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:Double x:Name="Lat">48.2</x:Double>
                            <x:Double x:Name="Long">-106.6501939</x:Double>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </maps:Position>
                    <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                    <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                </x:Arguments>
            </maps:MapSpan>
        </x:Arguments>
    </maps:Map>
```

I then get a location from a db search, drop a pin at that location and pan to it:

```
    private void MoveMap(Quarter location)
    {
        var pin = new Pin();
        pin.Position = new Position(location.Lat, location.Lon);
        pin.Label = locationEntry.Text;
        MoveMap(pin);
    }
    private void MoveMap(Pin pin)
    {
        amap.Pins.Add(pin);
        amap.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(pin.Position, 0.1, 0.1));
    }
```

[image: google map in app]

So far so good, but if I click on the pin it gets better...

[image: better google map]

I'm looking for a way to get the links to Google maps on the bottom to appear right off the bat. I would also like to make the label show on the pin. I've tried calling `amap.SendMapClicked(pin.Position)` right after the call to MoveToRegion, but nothing happens.

And finally I would like to display the "mode selector" from Google maps, which switches between satellite and default.

Is any of this possible? Lots of googling doesn't give me much hope.

Comment: Pin has a SendMarkerClicked method - use that.

Comment: @Jason that doesn't do anything either. It returns false. I've added `pin.SendMarkerClick();`after my call to MoveToRegion in the second MoveMap function above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working for me

```
    private void MoveMap(Quarter location)
    {
        var pin = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(location.Lat, location.Lon),
            Label = locationEntry.Text
        };
        amap.Pins.Add(item.Pins);
        amap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude),
Distance.FromMiles(50)));

    }
```

Comment: I already have that part working. It's the subsequent `sendMapClicked` or `sendMarkerClicked` that doesn't work for me. Of course I'm only trying to trigger the click to get the links displayed on the map, so an alternate way of accomplishing that is perfectly acceptable

Comment: This code helps you?

pin.InfoWindowClicked += async (s, args) => { await PinClicked((Pin)s); };

Comment: @FilipePilettiPlucenio no.